# How to make that 2d collider dont slide on on an inclined plane

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

If 2d collider with rigidbody with freezed Z rotation touches an inclined plane with its lower edge, then it begins to slide down, how to get rid of this effect? I want if rigidbody edge touch the inclined plane, rigidbody should keep his own position and dont slide down.

Comment: Add some friction?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with **BugFinder**, a frozen rotation on a **Rigidbody** will not affect the interaction between the collider and the inclined plane. You should create a new **PhysicsMaterial** and assign it to your **Collider** that is assigned to your **Rigidbody**. Increase either its **staticFriction**, **dynamicFriction**, or both, as well as experimenting with the **frictionCombine** option, which will change how the friction value of your **Rigidbody** will interact with the collider of the inclined plane.